# How to upload HTML documentation generated from Sphinx to GitHub?

Tags: python, github, python-sphinx

I just documented loads of my code and learnt how to use sphinx to generate the documentation. I want to include that into my GitHub project page but I do not know how to. Does anyone know existing tutorial or simple step to do so?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

github will serve static content for you using their [github pages](http://github.com/blog/272-github-pages) feature.  Essentially, you create a branch called gh-pages, into which you commit your static pages. The pages are then served at you.github.com/yourproject.

See the instructions at http://pages.github.com/.

You will likely run into an issue using Sphinx on github, because Sphinx uses directories with leading underscores.  You can fix this by adding a file called `.nojekyll` in the the directory with the generated sphinx html.

Comment: The link for the instructions is broken.

Comment: `.nojekyll` tip is life-saver. wish I had read this earlier. Further note: add it to the root of your html tree.

Comment: Link for what @Jayesh said above: https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages

Answer (score 5):

[John Paulett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622472/45773) is obviously correct and likely sufficient for most users already (+1).

Alternatively you might want to check out Ben Welsh's thorough tutorial [Sphinx documentation on GitHub](http://datadesk.latimes.com/posts/2012/01/sphinx-on-github/), which provides step by step instructions as well as a convenient [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) based script/task tying those together to get you started to *Quickly publish documentation alongside your code [...]* via a single command.

Comment: Sphinx documentation on GitHub said: ``you need to cre­ate an empty file in the root dir­ect­ory that lets Git­Hub know you aren’t us­ing Je­kyll to struc­ture your site.``

Answer (score 0):

[github-tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/github-tools/) has a feature doing exactly what you are asking for:

```
paver gh_pages_create gh_pages_build
```

Refer to the [excellent documentation](http://dinoboff.github.com/github-tools) (of course using itself) for how to set it up for your project.