# how to port python sphinx-doc to github pages?

Tags: python, git, github, python-sphinx, github-pages

I just followed [How to upload html documentation generated from sphinx to github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553800/how-to-upload-html-documentation-generated-from-sphinx-to-github) and everything works fine until I uploaded it to my github. I intend to make it as my personal website and I didn't make `gh-pages` branch. It looks something like this:

[image]

but it should look something like this, which I look from local:

[image]

Does anyone know what went wrong? I did include ".nojekyll" in the root. All the files generated directly from `make html` (however, I didn't upload files in "doctree"; only files in "html")

Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file name should be `.nojekyll` not `.nojekyII` :(